# Is it possible to pass different props from two different files in React?

Tags: reactjs, components, rendering, render, react-component

Suppose I am calling a Component from the index.js and the same component is called off from a different file with a completely different set of props inside a return value. The below images are the two files and the component itself. The Modal component has a dependency on the Home component's `toggle` state. It will only render when the toggle is true, which is controlled by the button in Home Component. Keep in mind I'm rendering the Modal component in App.js and in Home.js

***This is a small demo of a more realistic situation.*

After running this application Modal component is not rendering at all.
So the question is why is this happening internally and how to resolve this situation?

```
                import React, {useState} from 'react'
                import logo from './logo.svg';
                import './App.css';
                import Home from './components/Home';
                import Modal from './components/Modal';

                function App() {

                  const [logoR, setLogoR] = useState(logo);
                  const [currDate, setCurrDate] = useState(new Date());

                  console.log(currDate);

                  return (
                    <div className="App">
                      <header className="App-header">
                        <img src={logoR} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                        <p>
                          Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
                        </p>
                        <a
                          className="App-link"
                          href="https://reactjs.org"
                          target="_blank"
                          rel="noopener noreferrer"
                        >
                          Learn React
                        </a>
                        <Home/>
                        <Modal logoR={logoR} currDate={currDate} />
                      </header>
                      
                    </div>
                  );
                }

                export default App;
```

Github repo - [React-props](https://github.com/sujoyduttajad/React-props)

[image: Home component]

[image: Modal component]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `handleClick()` your return the Modal but nothing is being done with that. It's not being inserted into the DOM anywhere.

Something like this might get you closer.

```
import React, {usestate} trom 'react' 7.2K (gzipped: 3K)
import Modal from './Modal';
const Home = () => {
 const [toggle, set Toggle] = usestate(false);
 console.log(toggle);
                                
 const handleclick () => {
   setToggle(!toggle); 
    
 }
 return (
   <div>
        <button
            className="App-button"
            onclick={handleclick)>
            whats up!
        </button>
        <Modal toggle={toggle} />
   </div>
}
export default Home
```

I would suggest checking out react portals if you have a modal that you will want to trigger from various parts of the app. They have a good example of how to use this with a modal.

https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: That's something new, I will definitely try to understand portals. But I still don't know why the way I'm trying is not rendering the component.

Comment: Updated answer with example - should render modal but maybe not from correct page. Many ways to do that but some sort of global state may be helpful

Comment: Like you mean using redux? How can I store the onClick value in the redux store?

Comment: Redux is one option of many. Redux Toolkit is pretty simple setup now. You could use that to store a boolean like `isModalOpen` that you can access in the modal and toggle from any other component.